# What would be a good way to visualize variables in memory? (A visual debugger)

Tags: java, debugging, stack, visualization

I wrote a in-browser java-esque debugger for my students ( http://www.kapparate.com/kj/ . Click the compile button in a javascript enabled browser ), and I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to visualize the variables in the current scope. Right now, I'm printing them as JSON:

```
6 KJDB> 7 STACK {"x":"hello","y":"hello","a":4,"z":5,"xx":-5.6400000000000015,"c":true,"intArray":[5,90,35,45,150,3]}
```

So that represents x, y, a, z, xx, c, and an intArray. The respective values are there too.

However, some of my students are in middle school, and this kind of notation has been confusing at times. Should I use a table (each row being a different variable?). Or perhaps something graphical with rectangles representing variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two column table, with names and values. When you get to talk about method invocation and possibly recursion you might want to use different borders to mark different stack frames. Or you could mark stack frames with a single a column heading containing the method name.

Answer (score 0):

What my professor did in my Intro to CS course was to draw a really wide rectangle to represent the computer's memory, and then separate it into columns (so one row that's arbitrarily long, and then many columns, also of arbitrary width).

Whenever you create a variable, he would use a small block to either represent the variable or represent the reference to that variable. For example, an `int` variable would simply take up one small column or "block" of memory. But for an `int[]` variable (or any other kind of variable that is passed by reference instead of by value), he would draw a block to represent the reference, then draw another block down the row to represent the actual values. He would simply draw arrows to show that the smaller block referenced the larger block.